# PHP Generate random numbers as array shows (by click a selection box)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop

I am beginner of studying PHP and I started to study the Looping and array by using PHP with Mysql. Now I met a problem which is generate random numbers as array, based on the amount of random numbers that we chose from the selection box (1-10).

It means that I click '9' in the selection box, then click the submit button, it will show 9 random number as array format (e.g. [213,452,6773......due to 9th random number])

i know how to implement and the logic of operations but I am not good at coding on Looping and array. I hope someone can helps me, Cheers.

Comment: Somebody downvoted your question...Recently some group of people I think are giving lot of down votes(I got some for no reason)!!dont know whats their problem. There must be a good filter methods for down voting,because any one can press the down arrow,it costs them nothing.

Comment: @NidhinDavid It's perfectly alright if someone down-voted this question. Take your mouse pointer over the down-vote arrow and you'll see that this question lacks research effort and can be down-voted. Whomsoever down-voted was perfectly within the site's terms of use.

Comment: Thank you for everyone helping me to solve the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your select box `howMany` and then `POST` that form to this code

```
if(isset($_POST["howMany"]))
{
    $max=intval($_POST["howMany"]);    // Checks how many numbers to generate
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++)             // Loops that many times
    {
      $numbers[$i]=rand(1,1000);       // Generates a rand between 1 to 1000
    }                                  // and adds to array 
    print_r($numbers);                 // here is your array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$x=9;//this is your desired no of random numbers
for ($i = 0; $i < $x; ++$i) {  
    $array[] = rand(1,10);//rand function will generate random numbers between given values
}
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume your input number is saved in variable `$numRandoms`

```
$randomArray = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= $numRandoms; $i++) 
{
      $randomArray[] = rand(1 , 10000);
}
```

You can obviously change the parameters in the `rand` function to have a different range.

The for loop loops through the number of random numbers needed, and the `$randomArray[]` assigns a new number to a new array position each time.